# Riak solution for querying data by books or unique pages

Tags: riak, riak-search

Consider a set of data called *Library*, which contains a set of *Books* and each book contains a set of *Pages*.

Let's say you are using Riak to store this data, and you need to be access the data in two possible ways:
- Query for a particular page (with a unique id)
- Query for all pages in a particular book (with a unique name)

Additionally, you need to be able to easily update and delete pages of a particular *Book*.

What would be the best way to accomplish this in Riak?

Obviously Riak Search will do the trick, but maybe is inefficient for what I am trying to do. I am wondering if it makes sense to set up buckets where each bucket can be a *Book* (which would make for potentially millions of "Book" buckets). Maybe that is a bad idea...

Can this be accomplished with secondary indexes?

I am trying to keep this simple...

I am new to Riak and I am trying to find the best way to accomplish something that is probably relatively simple. I would appreciate any help from the Stack Overflow community. Thanks!

Comment: I think this might have something to do with this, but I would still appreciate an answer: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/appendices/concepts/Links/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to model master-detail relationships in Riak is to have the master record contain a list of detail record IDs, possibly together with some information about the detail record that may be useful when deciding which detail records to retrieve.

In your example, you could have two buckets called 'books' and 'pages'. The master record in the 'books' bucket will contain metadata and information about the book as a whole together with a list of pages that are included in the book. Each page would contain the ID of the 'pages' record holding the page data as well as the corresponding page number. If you e.g. wanted to be able to query by chapter, you could also add information about which chapters a certain page belongs to.

The 'pages' bucket would contain the text of the page and possibly links to images and other media data that are included on that page. This data could be stored in yet another bucket.

In order to get a specific page or a range of pages, one would first retrieve the master record from the 'books' bucket and then based on the contents of the record the appropriate pages. Even though this requires several GET operations, they are all direct lookups based on keys, which is the most efficient and scalable way to retrieve data from Riak, so it is will perform and scale well.

This approach also makes it simple to change the order of pages and/or chapters as only the master record needs to be updated. Adding, deleting or modifying pages would however require both the master record as well as one or more detail records to be updated, added or deleted.

You can most certainly also solve this problem by adding secondary indexes to the objects and query based on this. Secondary index queries in Riak does however have to include processing on a covering set (generally ring size / n_val) of partitions in order to fulfil the request, and therefore puts a bit more load on the system and generally results in higher latencies than retrieving a single object containing keys through a direct key lookup (which only needs to involve the partitions where the object is actually stored).

Although maintaining a separate object containing indexes adds a bit of extra work when inserting or deleting pages/entries, this approach will generally result in more efficient reads, as only direct key lookups are required. If your application is heavy on reads, it probably makes sense to use this approach, while secondary indexes could be more efficient for a write heavy application as inserts and modifications are made cheaper at the expense of more expensive reads. You can however always add secondary indexes just in case in order to keep your options open.

In cases like this I would usually recommend performing some benchmarks to test the solutions and chech which solution that best matches you particular performance and scaling requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I think the biggest caveat of this approach is the last part that you mentioned - regarding adding/removing a page. Do you see any drawback in storing only pages and using a secondary index to store the book's unique id with each page?

Comment: In Riak secondary indexes defined as record metadata, and in order to modify indexes of a set of objects, one needs to read and modify all of them. My assumption here is that it must be possible to identify and retrieve a specific page/set of pages by the page number(s). If you choose to put this in the key and/or secondary indexes, you may need to update multiple pages when inserting or deleting pages, as all pages following the ones you change may need to be renumbered. For this reason I would think keeping the index in a single object would make updates easier as well as more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for the comment (and sorry for the long time to respond). The book/pages example is truthfully a generalization. We actually have items that belong to catalogs in some cases or pages that belong to pdf's in other cases. The point is that we have items that we need to be able to access on their own and also in a group (varying levels of granularity). The order of items in a set does not matter. I merely need to be able to access "all items in a set named X" or "a single specific item Y". For this, I think a secondary index is perfect. Do you agree?

Comment: I do not think there is any doubt that it would work with secondary indexes, but depending on your access patterns it may or may not be the most efficient and scalable approach. I have updated my response with some things to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and insightful answer. I appreciate that you addressed a concern that I had regarding updates/deletes to the "book" and pointed out the pros and cons of the two possible methods in terms whether we are primarily reading or updating. In general, your answer gave me a better understanding of best practices in Riak.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way will be to store hole book as an one object, and duplicate it's pages as another separate objects.
Pros:

- you will be able to select any object by its key(the most cheapest op
  in riak is kv query)
- any query will be predicted by latency
- this is natural way of storing for riak

Cons:

- If you need to update any page you must update whole book, and then page. As riak doesn't have atomic ops, you must to think how to recover any failure situation (like this: book was updated, but page was not).

Riak is about availability predictable latency, so if you will use something like 2i to collect results, it will make unpredictable time query, which will grow with page numbers